# Spring SAML 2.0 : why format attribute of saml:NameID tag is referring to saml 1.1 although we are using saml 2.0

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I have downloaded the sample project on spring-saml 2.0. I have noticed that in the Assertion.xml file under the saml:NameID tag, Format tag is referring to saml 1.1. Would anyone please clarify why? I am new to Spring-saml 2.0 and I have no idea of earlier saml version?

```
 <saml:Subject>

<saml:NameID NameQualifier="http://idp.ssocircle.com" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:**SAML:1.1**:nameid-format:emailAddress">test@abc.com</saml:NameID>


<saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:**SAML:2.0**:cm:bearer">

<saml:SubjectConfirmationData Recipient="http://192.168.1.100:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/SSO" NotOnOrAfter="2016-02-26T05:23:54.000Z" InResponseTo="a37gbidcfgff98de3064i3eij6ee7bj"/>

</saml:SubjectConfirmation>

</saml:Subject>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

Relevant constants which were available as part of previous SAML version are re-used in SAML 2.0. The values are part of the SAML 2.0 specification which you can refer to to find details.